# Apple silicion M1: How to compile a architecture x86_64 dylib file to architecture arm64

Tags: architecture, arm64, jrebel, apple-silicon

As is known, M1 needs arm64 architecture programs.
My question is how to compile a architecture x86_64 dylib file to architecture arm64?

For example, I have a file:
`"/var/folders/7p/m6699wbs015dhlp_hkwl84t80000gn/T/jrebel-JRebel-202102261201-griffin/lib/libjrebel64.dylib"`

```bash
 > file libjrebel64.dylib 
 > libjrebel64.dylib (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I want build this file to architecture arm64, how could I do it?
Through jrebel has an update and support M1 recently, I'm still courious about it if I can build this by myself.

Comment: Are you asking how to obtain the source code of a closed-source binary?

Comment: actually I just want to do an architecture transfer, and make my program can work normally :)

Comment: You need the source for that. Or you can install Rosetta, but then you'll keep building an x86_64 binary...